# Why isn't my python program printing my desired results from an sql query?

Tags: python, database, output, database-connection

I'm writing my python program using IDLE and whenever I run

```
python3 [myfilename]
```

in my terminal it doesn't output what it's supposed to be outputting from the SQL query I made.

I've tried to see if the problem was with these 2 lines:

```
c = db.cursor()
c.execute("select content time from posts order by time desc")
```

and guessed that maybe

```
db.cursor() = c
db.cursor(execute("select * from posts))
posts = db.fetchall()

print(add_post());
```

would actually add something but I get no output! Basically, I want it to print out anything from my database.

```
def get_posts():
    db = psycopg2.connect(database="forum")
    c = db.cursor()
    c.execute("select content, time from posts order by time desc")
    posts = c.fetchall()
    db.close()

get_posts()
print(get_posts)
```

I expect my output to print any data in terminal but running the file doesn't actually print anything. Please help!

---

EDIT: my new error in IDLE is "Is the server running locally and accepting
    connections on Unix domain socket" 
can anybody help me out here with this?

Comment: have you checked that your code is actually valid python syntax?

Comment: yes, it is valid because i run through idle. import psycopg2 is at the top of my file

Comment: Maybe i am missing something but when i try to run this i get a syntax error relating the `c.execute` line where it looks like open then close double quotes then write the query but not inside a string. then open and close double quotes at the end of the query.

Comment: Ok, I've fixed the problem with quotes. When I run my file, I get an error Is the server running locally and accepting
 connections on Unix domain socket. Any idea what's going on?

Comment: That message is just informational - that's how postgres works when conncting locally.

Answer (score 1):

You need to return something from your `get_posts` function.  As it is your printing the *function* *object* `get_posts`, which will look something like `<function get_post at 0x7f42d60bcf28>`

Your could ought to look something like this:

```
def get_posts():
    db = psycopg2.connect(database="forum")
    c = db.cursor()
    c.execute("""select content, time from posts order by time desc""")
    posts = c.fetchall()
    db.close()
    # Return a value
    return posts

# Call the function and assign the return value to a variable
the_posts = get_posts()
# Print the variable
print(the_posts)
```

Comment: When I run my file, I get an error Is the server running locally and accepting connections on Unix domain socket. Any idea what's going on with this?